# Organize exported data on a csv file (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, csv

I am running this script;

```
profilelist=("mgmt","poc","prod","sdlc","drivevelocity","partner","dynamicenvironments") #Accounts we currently have in AWS

$regions=("us-east-1","us-east-2","us-west-1","us-west-2","ap-south-1","ap-northeast-2","ap-northeast-3","ap-southeast-1","ap-southeast-2","ap-northeast-1","ca-central-1","eu-central-1","eu-west-1","eu-west-2","eu-west-3","eu-north-1","sa-east-1") #Regions we currently use in AWS

$ports=("22","3389") #SSH port, RDP port

$output="$home"
          $output+="/downloads"
          $output+="/SG_PublicIP.csv" #Path to find the output csv file

$csv="SG_PublicIP.csv" #Name of the csv file

$csv = "$output"
if (Test-Path $output) {
   Remove-Item $csv
}

foreach($profile in $profilelist){
    foreach($region in $regions){
      foreach($port in $ports){

    #The following AWS command will list all of the available security groups that contain public IP addresses within range of ports 22 and 3389. It will then output a csv file with the information for every account profile and region available.
          
    aws ec2 describe-security-groups --region $region --profile $profile --filters Name=ip-permission.from-port,Values=$port Name=ip-permission.to-port,Values=$port Name=ip-permission.cidr,Values='0.0.0.0/0' --query "SecurityGroups[*].[GroupName]"  | out-file $output -Encoding ASCII -append 

    }
   }
   }
```

It exports the Excel CSV file with a list of all the security groups. My issue is that I want it to export the data cleanly and organized in columns per profile. So for example;

**Profile1 | Profile2 | Profile3 | Profile4**

**SG data  | SG data  | SG data  | SG data**

Trying to find how to export a clean CSV file.

[image: Output CSV file]

Comment: Does your `aws` command have an "output as Csv" flag?

Comment: You want a pivot table.  What you want is each region on a separate line and each profile in a different column.  If you post sample of you existing output file I will post the code.

Comment: @jdweng I posted a picture of how the CSV file looks.

Comment: Pictures do not help.

Comment: To create a csv, you need to output **objects** and capture those objects at the beginning of the first loop like `$result = foreach($profile in $profilelist){..}`. Then when the loop is finished output all that with cmdlet `Export-Csv`. Use `Select-Object` to specify the properties you need from the aws command